# Problem with fetching records from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have huge problem with getting data from MySQL base because of this error:

> Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/AMPPS/www/Maciej/search.php on line 44

Tried to do something wtih this by deleting line with connection close but the end result is only blank page without requested data. The goal is to make nutrition calcultor with connection to databse. I tried to test if the code could get any result but it failed as it is described above. Also IDE screams on me with commmuicate that it can't resolve the columns in request. Thank you for your help!

In hints please write in which line could be the problem because communication between us will be better. If you got some comments to code itself it will be great help too. Everybody, thank you for your help!

```
session_start();

require_once 'connect.php';

$conn = @new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db_name, $db_table);
if ($conn->connect_errno!=0)
{
    echo 'Error:'.$conn->connect_errno;
}
else
{
    $product = $_GET['product'];
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Food_db, mytable WHERE Product = '$product'";

    if($result = @$conn->query($sql))
    {
        $how_many = $result->num_rows;
        if ($how_many==1 and $amount>0)
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['Product']= $row['Product'];
            $_SESSION['Proteins']= $amount * $row['Proteins'];
            $_SESSION['Fats']= $amount * $row['Fats'];
            $_SESSION['Carbohydrates']= $amount * $row['Carbohydrates'];
            $_SESSION['Calories']= $amount * $row['Calories'];


            unset($_SESSION['Error']);
            $result->close();
            header('Location:result.php');

        }else{
            $_SESSION['Amount_error'] = 'You have to add amount!';
            $_SESSION['Error:'] = 'Ups record not in base';
            header('Location:index.php');

        }
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Do you know **why** you use those **@** ? Get rid of them and see what errors you get

Comment: Your problem is probably located in connector.php

Comment: Is it correct to put the database name `Food_db` inside your query like that? I haven't seen it done in that way, especially as your connection already specifies the database. Also, don't concatenate user input into queries - use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I think i found the problem, it's ampps - dosen't want to start mysql server. Dunno what to do :(